# Multithreading in java - score list of unknown amount of players

Tags: java, multithreading

I am working on a simple server-client dice-game for university project. The game restriction is that there can be infinite number of players. I am trying to create the list of their scores, but I have no idea how to pass the amount of players, as each time the next player connects, the server accepts new connection, so I cannot prevent next thread from being started.

I was thinking of something like "PLAY" button/boolean variable while waiting for players and right after the game is started, the next thread would be unavailable to start.However, I have no idea how to implement it. Any suggestions? Another idea would also be a good suggestion :)

Here is the code snippet from server:

```
 public void initializeResultList(int amountOfPlayers){
    final ArrayList<Object> resultDescription = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<Object> zeros = new ArrayList(); 
    resultDescription.add("Player");
    resultDescription.add("One Pair");
    resultDescription.add("Two Pairs");
    resultDescription.add("Three of a kind");
    resultDescription.add("Full House");
    resultDescription.add("Four of a kind");
    resultDescription.add("Five of a kind");
    for (int j = 0; j < resultDescription.size(); j++){
        zeros.add(null);
    }
    resultList.add(resultDescription);
    //fill with nulls, then there will be player Scores
    for (int i = 1; i <= amountOfPlayers; i++){
        resultList.add(zeros);
    }

}

 public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {


    int portNumber = 444;

    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;


    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error finding port");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    // program loop
    do {
        Server server = new Server(serverSocket.accept());

        //HERE IS THE PROBLEM!
        server.initializeResultList(2); // here should be passed the amount
        server.start();
    } while (true);

}

@Override
public void run(){
    System.out.println("Connection accepted");
    System.out.println("Client has successfully connected");
}
```

Here is code from Player class (it's not the issue right now, but maybe you would like to know how the server and player communicates):

```
  public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {
    //Connect to the server
    Socket socket = null;
    int portNumber = 444;
    String str;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    PrintWriter out = null;

    try {
        socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), portNumber);
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    } catch (UnknownHostException uhe) {
        System.out.println("Unknown Host");
        System.exit(0);
    }


    boolean quit = false;

    while (!quit) {

        str = input.readLine();
        out.println(str);
    }


}
```

Comment: If im reading your question right, you could wait until the server encounters some kind of signal from your client to halt processing. I.e. instead of sending just raw data to the server, append a header-string (something like 'end-stream:false;data:yourstring' or 'end-data:true;data:yourstring') and parse it out on the server. You would then not need to know the number you are passing, as telling the thread when to stop processing is part of the data itself. Consider checking out the cursor pattern.

Comment: Hmm, So you mean that the client does some action that prevents server from connecting to more threads? I don't get this solution with header-string :(

Comment: Well, I think the fundamental problem you are trying to deal with isn't to do with multi-threading really. Think about how you can could send or receive a dataset which is arbitrary in size. You would need to also send along some meta-data about that set so you know how large it is OR send a token to the server telling it when that dataset ends... In practical terms you do not need to use multi-threading on your server at all. In fact, setting up so many threads is incredibly inefficient in terms of computing resources.

Comment: Unfortunately it has to be multithreaded, as it is one of the requirements of the final project at univesity :(

Answer (score 0):

there are several possible implementations for this. One that comes to mind, includes a queue of players.  So whenever a new player connects,  it sits in the queue until your application picks it up. Queue size can be added to the local counter to get the total number of players. After you pulled the player he's gone from the queue. 
For instance you can initialize the queue in the following way:

```
Queue<YourObject> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<YourObject>();
```

We pick up the concurrent linked queue because of its properties that you can check [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html). When a new user is added you can put the Player in the queue with:

```
queue.offer(myObject);
```

while in your servlet, for instance at the end of each round or whenever you need the new Player, you can call:

```
YourObject myObject = queue.poll();
```

or you can get the number of new players calling:

`int nrNewPlayers = queue.size()`;

If you need the Player object, containing also info and statistics about the player itself, this is a good solution. However if you really need just the total number of players, then the queue is overkill and you could just use A[tomic integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) in the follwing way:

```
//Initialize the integer in constructor
public static AtomicInteger userCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);

//Increment number of users when a new user is added ()
userCounter.incrementAndGet();

//Decrement the number of users when a user disconnects
userCounter.decrementAndGet();

//Get number of users from within your code
int counter = userCounter.intValue();
```

so your server code would be:

```
//HERE IS THE PROBLEM!
int counter = userCounter.intValue();
server.initializeResultList(counter); // here should be passed the amount
```

This is the best that I can do with the code that you provided. If you'd like more help please create a new question and provide more code instead of snippets and a better explanation of what you need. Hope this will help you though.

Comment: How exactly? Maybe a simple example? Which queue should I use? Concurrent Linked or different?